# how __builtin_frame_address() get the frame pointer

Tags: linux, stack-trace

In linux, `backtrace()` can be used to print the function stack trace. Basically, `backtrace()` get access to the current stack frame by `invoking __builtin_frame_address()`, so, how is `__builtin_frame_address()` work? Where can the source code of `__builtin_frame_address()` be found?

Comment: Look in the source of your compiler.

Comment: It's 'builtin'. It's not a function, it's an instruction to the compiler to emit instructions to acquire it.